# can latency of usb-serial port be programmed?

Tags: delphi, serial-port, usb, latency, modbus

I'm using standard windows routines to access the (usb to) serial port. Is there a way to program (i use delphi) the parameter which is available in windows 8's device manager under ports->usb serial port->properties->port settings->advanced->BM options->latency. Due to this latency, which is 16 ms by default, my cbInQue resolution is too low. I'd prefer 1 ms, but don't know how to make my application change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. All you can do is look up the setting in the registry and check whether it is correct.

It might be possible to change it there too, but I wouldn't do that.

Comment: was afraid it's so. btw if you can recommend how to translate the port number to registry entry (i see there are some under HKLM\system\currentcontrolset\usb\) pls do and thx.

Comment: You are not telling us, which USB to serial port converter you are using. If it is FTDI, there is the FTD2XX.DLL which gives you quite a few options. The API is also documented: http://www.ftdichip.com/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer's_Guide(FT_000071).pdf The entries in the registry under HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\FTDIBUS are also documented. I can't provide any code because that's my employer's property.

Comment: The latency is stored in the entry LatencyTimer.

Comment: Yes, seems it's FTDI here now, and the previous one i had was FTDI too (according to the online specs). I know nothing about this subject but i'm improving as i type... The code is not needed, the keywords/hints you provided are enough to get me going. Thanks again.